# Select another option if input not empty in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some code in my react component:

```
<legend>Data:</legend>
          <Input type="text" name="Payment" id="Payment" className="validate[required, custom[integer], max[9999999999999]]" placeholder="2000" addonBefore="Payment" addonAfter="cents" />
          <Input type="text" name="Value" id="Value" className="validate[required, custom[integer], max[9999999999999]]" placeholder="3500" addonBefore="Value" addonAfter="cents" />
          <Input type="select" label="Some code" placeholder="placeholder" >
            <option value="0">option1</option>
            <option value="1">option2</option>
            <option value="2">option3</option>
          </Input>
          <Input type="select" label="Some category" placeholder="Category">
            <option value="0">category1</option>
            <option value="1">category2</option>
            <option value="2">category3</option>
            <option value="3">Category4</option>
            <option value="4">Category5</option>
          </Input>
          <Input type="select" label="Another code" placeholder="some code">
            <option value="1">code1</option>
            <option value="2">code2</option>
            <option value="3">code3</option>
            <option value="4">code4</option>
            <option value="5">code5</option>
            <option value="8">code6</option>
            <option value="7">code7</option>
          </Input>
      </fieldset>
```

How can i change select option for example in "Some category", if input payment not empty? I mean, if user enter some text in "Payment" input(for example), select option must be changed from default to second or third. And something like that with another text input and select option? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I came to this code(it's worked for me and solve my problem):

```
state : {
  text: '',
  select: 0
},
handleChange({target: {id, value}}) {
  const data = {[id]: value};
  if (id == 'Payment' && value.length != 0) {
    data.select = 4;
  } else if (id == 'Value' && value.length != 0){
    data.select = 2;
  } else {
    data.select = 0;
  }
  this.setState(data);
},
/* some code in render fucntion for our form*/
```

Maybe it will be helpfull for someone.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make all your inputs - [controlled](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)
Save input values to a `state` of your component and based on those values perform the logic you need to render different `options`

```
  <select value={this.state.myValue} onChange={this.handleChange}>
    <option value="A">Apple</option>
    <option value="B">Banana</option>
    <option value="C">Cranberry</option>
  </select>
```

You need to use `value` attribute instead of `defaultValue` to make your select - **controlled**
Read more in [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-select-value)

Comment: You mean add onChange for every text input and function(for example handleChange), inside which I check if value empty or not and than choose needed select option? How can i change select option from defaultValue to second or third for example?

Comment: You need to use  `setState` to save `value` in `onChange` event and then in render function you can use this `value` to control other select element

Comment: Hm, ok. I have some code like this: `handleSelect() {
     this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }`. How can i use this value to control other select? using some ternary operators, like that `<Input type="select" defaultValue={this.value == '' ? '0' : '2'}> `? I'm newbie in react so i just don't know how use text input value for changing select option in render fucntion.

Comment: `<Input type="select" value={this.v‌​alue == '' ? '0' : '2'}>` but you can use `defaultValue` if you dont want it to be controlled. I suggest you to read documentration first.